# Play a default ringtone when i send a notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried to notify a notification with ringtone. I tried many code but its doesn't work .
i want to play a default ringtone when i send a notification .
notification is proper sent by me ..
but there is no sound in mobile .

My Code is

```
  public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

   private static final String TAG = "FCMPlugin";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    Log.d(TAG, "==> MyFirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived");

    if( remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Message: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("wasTapped", false);
    for (String key : remoteMessage.getData().keySet()) {
            Object value = remoteMessage.getData().get(key);
            Log.d(TAG, "\tKey: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            data.put(key, value);
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Data: " + data.toString());
    FCMPlugin.sendPushPayload( data );
    //sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getData());
}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, Map<String, Object> data) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FCMPluginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    for (String key : data.keySet()) {
        intent.putExtra(key, data.get(key).toString());
    }
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying this on an emulator it would not work because, if I'm not mistaken, it does not have a default ringtone set at:

```
content://settings/system/ringtone
```

Have you tried testing

```
Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

On an actual device?

Comment: yes i have tried this . but it is not working in any mobile .

Answer (score 0):

Check Whether your app is in the background. If the app is in the background the onMessageReceived function is not called hence no ringtone.